# phpmyadmin on IIS 7.5 Server 2008R2 white screen

Tags: php, mysql, iis, phpmyadmin

Ok, did my best to check all pre-req:

PHP 5.3 is in the path, and added to Handler Mappings in IIS
2) in php.ini I added the following:

```
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext"
session.save_path="C:\sessionfolder\php"
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
```

Created a config.inc.php according to many of the tutorials I found.

Tested phpinfo with a test.php (which loads fine, so clearly PHP has functionality), and I can see that mysqli and mbstring extensions are all enabled.  However when I attempt to hit the root (index.php, which I did add to default documents) I just get a white screen.  (One note, it does not appear that the PHP session is using the  `session.save_path`  location specified in php.ini, and instead using `c:\windows\temp`)

Tried adding error reporting to the index.php as follows:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

But no errors are shown.
Used Process Monitor to track php-cgi.exe or w3wp.exe, and saw no "ACCESS DENIED" messages.

Running out of troubleshooting steps, hoping someone can help shed some light for me.

Comment: follow this step: http://blog.pluralsight.com/install-phpmyadmin-on-iis7-and-server-2008 you might be missing a step or required plugins

Comment: Do you have it running on a port other then 80 or tend to change your HOST file?

Comment: unixmiah --> That is one of the tutorials I followed.

haxtbh --> I am using port 80 (will probably change to 443, once I get the basics working).  The entries are fully qualified within my DNS server, so resolution is working fine.